# Ajax call to WebAPI goes to Error instead of success

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a Ajax call to a WebApi method. My Call is looks like this:

```
 function CalculateAmortizationScheduleAPI()
    {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:62815/v1/APR/Calculate',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    "LoanAmount": 200000,
                    "Costs": 100,
                    "Term": 15,
                    "Rate": 2.2,
                    "RateType": 2,
                    "Points": 1,
                    "MIRate": 2.2,
                    "UFMIRate": 2,
                    "FixedTerm": 5,
                    "FirstPaymentDate": "10/10/2017",
                    "RateChangeDate": "10/10/2018",
                    "AdjustTerm": 2,
                    "IndexRate": 2,
                    "Margin": 2,
                    "AdjustmentCapFirst": 2,
                    "AdjustmentCap": 2,
                    "AdjustmentCapLifetime": 2,
                    "EstimatedPropertyValue": 2,
                    "CancelMIPMonths": 2,
                    "CancelMIPLTV": 2,
                    "AdditionalPricipalPayment": 2,
                    "ConstantPaymentValue": 2
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success");

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            },
        });
    }
```

And this is my WebApi method that Ajax call successfully hit when I put the breakpoints and also the return value has value as a object.

```
     [HttpPost]
     public Dictionary<int, AmItem> Calculate([FromBody]AmArguments 
     lAmArguments)
    {

     .....

     return AmSchedule;
      }
```

The problem is that even though the Ajax call hit the method but the Success method is not executing and the Error Alert will appear in the screen, Also I don't know how to capture return value that is complex object.

Comment: write your error function as  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)  and look at jqXHR.status and jqXHR.responseText to see what exactly happening with your API call.

Comment: you ajax expect json as response confirm your are returning json

Comment: @omi the method is returning object as  Dictionary<int, AmItem>

Comment: @Hakunamatata when I do that no popup appears at all.

Comment: @nik in Google chrome  you can put a break point in your ajax code and step through it. Hit F12 in chrome and in source tab find your ajax function and put break point and step through your code.

Comment: @Hakunamatata I do that, when it goes to the webAPI method it is not going back to Ajax code only shows the Error alert in page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dataType: 'json',

> Its mean return type of data from server should be json

Make sure are you returning json object to ajax success call back - if not then you need to change it to 
dataType: 'text',

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead
>    More detial please visit - [Visit](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

I hope this will work fine for you - still you facing error please comment below

Comment: Let me knw did u change return type ?